# Not able to debug response from asyncRestTemplate.exchange

Tags: java, spring, debugging, resttemplate

I have written code to post a request to a web service, which also post request to another webservice.

```
    Future<ResponseEntity<String>> response = asyncRestTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, requestPayload, String.class);
try {
                String res= response.get().getBody().toString();
            } catch (){
}
```

Now I am trying to debug via posting request to this service via postman.
I am able to hit this post function and breakpoint reaches

> response.get().getBody().toString();

statement. After that I am not able to hit any breakpoint further in code.

But I can see response in postman?

Why this is happening? Ideally I should be able to see response after response.get() call.

Any ideas.

Comment: Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: no, nothing in logs

Comment: did you try inspect on response.get().getBody().toString(); ?

Comment: i cannot do that since i am.not able to hit any breakpoint after that

Comment: once the break point reaches response.get().getBody().toString(); select the line and press Ctrl+Shift+i